# How to use OR in substring index with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to filter word in my string
From the command below, I can output word in "TCP" filter

```
awk '{print substr($0, index($0, "{TCP}"))}'
```

This is my example input

```
01/08-21:03:05.312358 [] [1:5000001:1] Attack Detected [] [Priority: 0] {TCP} 139.150.160.188:40001 -> 192.168.2.1:80`
```

so I want the ip to be extracted after `{TCP}`. I have already extracted by using `sed`. I wonder if the log file has `{ICMP}` and `{UDP}` protocol, can I filter it by using `||` between string to act like OR operation?

can I also filter it for UDP and ICMP by using "OR" in filter? Can it be done like this...?

```
 awk '{print substr($0, index($0, "{TCP}" || "{UDP}" ||"{ICMP}"))}'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible with `awk`, but the REGEXP syntax works somewhat different from the `C`-style boolean operators. Assuming you want to extract the IP address in all cases you mentioned, the following should work:

```
awk '{if (match($0,/{(TCP|UDP|ICMP)} ([[:digit:]:.]{15})/,v)) print(v[2])}' logfile.txt
```

This uses the `match` function of `awk` to search for the string `TCP` or `UDP` or `ICMP`, followed by a space and than an IPv4 (i.e. 15 characters consisting of digits `0-9` or the period `.`), and extracts the actual value of the latter part of the regular expression (which is sub-grouped in parentheses) and stores it in the `awk` internal array varuable `v`.

If such a match was found, it prints `v[2]` which is the actual value of the second `(...)` grouped sub-expression (the first being the OR-group for the procotols). *Notice that this use of the `match()` function requires GNU Awk!*

Note that since this is a simple action statement in which only one operation is performed if a condition (the `match()` call returning non-zero) is met, it could as well have been written in the usual "`<condition> { <actions> }`"-Syntax of `awk`, i.e.

```
awk 'match($0,/{(TCP|UDP|ICMP)} ([[:digit:]:.]{15})/,v)) {print v[2]}' logfile.txt
```

Comment: @EdMorton You correctly point out that this use of the `match()` function is specific to GNU awk, and I have amended the answer.